# printer installation kyocera taskalfa 1800

Tags: printing

I am a new user of Ubuntu. Please help me to install my Kyocera TASKalfa 1800. I installed it from downloading the printer driver from its site. But it asks me to install `usr/div/cups/filter` for Kyocera TASKalfa 1800. I am sending the print screen of trouble which I'm facing.

[image: screenshot]

Hi Arun...

My Source folder is in `/home/desktop`. But I don't know how to enter there. The second screenshot showing where is the .exe file rastertokpsl_A3 is. How can I reach there and install the file through cmd? Please answer me.

[image]

I have done upto that. But the problem is that folder contains only two files. I am sending you the third png file.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell how you installed the driver?

Comment: Are you malayali?

Comment: phew;  seems to me the commands are `cd Downloads` and then `unzip Linux_TASKalfa*` and that creates a directory called Linux so the next command is `cd Linux/64bit/Global` as you need to get inside the Global directory ..that is inside 64bit .. assuming you are using 64bit Ubuntu .. then when you get there you need to do `tar -zxvf English.tar.gz` if English is your language and then you run the install script in there, which is `./English/install.sh` and that should run an install script and install what you are missing, which is in that final directory and is "English/rastertokpsl_A3"

Comment: Yep,. I am Using linux 64. The rest are in edited question. Please answer

Answer (score 0):

so Manoj; I would suggest

1) open a terminal; ....... please ask how to if you do not know ..
2) paste these commands 
3) `cd Desktop`         .as that is where you say you downloaded the big file to ? next command asks the system to LIST what is there so it is `ls`

...... can you tell us if **Linux_TASKalfa1...200_v8.1305.zip** is there please?

.. if it is, then paste these commands into the terminal; one by one;

```
unzip Linux_TASKalfa1...200_v8.1305.zip
```

then `cd Linux/64bit/Global`

then `tar -zxvf English.tar.gz`

and then `./English/install.sh` and that should do the work for you

Comment: This answer solved my problem. great